# error sending request to nodejs whit Express using postman?

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, postman

I am trying to INSERT data in a table of MYSql using NodeJs, Express framework throw Postman with the POST method. I get an error. I dont know if it's about the parse of the json. or i have to send it different.

Json sended from postman(raw, JSON):

```
{
    "namel": "Teusaquillo",
    "area_2m": 6000,
    "parent": "chapinero"
}
```

When i send the request i get this error:

```
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (<mypaht>\nodeapi\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at <mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (<mypaht>nodeapi\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)<br> &nbsp`; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)</pre>
```

Other view of the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (<mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at <mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

This is the index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});
 
//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  ...
});     

app.post('/api/locations',(req, res) => {
  let data = {namel: req.body.namel, area_2m: req.body.area_2m, parent: req.body.parent};  
  let sql = "INSERT INTO location SET ?";
  let query = conn.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```

This is the table i am trying to fill:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `namel` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `area_2m` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`namel`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `location_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `location` (`namel`)
)
```

I'll apreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to send a request in other tools? For instance, Insomnia. Just to exclude the influence of a tool.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: In Insomnia i get this error.               SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @JRichardsz not yet. i made debug and the error is before ge into the function

Comment: Could you try with this `curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data` ??

Comment: @JRichardsz yes tghe error is befores enter to funcions. i tried ur curl comant ans doest works but after that i go to postmant again and it do. but i still having a problem with the GET with parameters. ´I have 2 path app.get('/api/locations/:id',(req, res) => {´ and ´app.post('/api/locations',(req, res) => {´ i send _http://localhost:3000/api/locations?id=chapinero_ but always go to the path without the  id like if i didnt send parameters

Answer (score 1):

In the postman make sure that you choose JSON (application/json)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data passed on query should an array?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});
 
//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  ...
});     

app.post('/api/locations',(req, res) => {
  // use destruction for easy reading
  let { namel, area_2m, parent } = req.body;
  // use mysql format to build query
  let sql = "INSERT INTO location SET ?";
  let value = [namel, area_2m, parent]
  let queryString = mysl.format(sql, value)
  let query = conn.query(queryString,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because of extra white space. Once I got rid of all extra white spaces between properties and between the opening parenthesis and the first key/property, it worked.

I am running NodeJS with express and I guess `express.json` throws an error instead of trimming out extra whitespace even though extra whitespace in json is perfectly valid json.